# Chizkuni Bereshis 38:9 - Why Was Onan Worried about his Crops?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, commentaries, agriculture, parashat-vayeishev, yibbum-chalitza-levirate

[Chizkuni, Bereshis 38:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Genesis.38.9.2-3?lang=he)

וידע אונן כסבור היה, כמו הידוע נדע

כי לא לו יהיה הזרע וגו' אמר בלבו אם אבא אל אשת אחי אשחית את ארצי שלא אמצא מי חורשה ומי זורעה.
לבלתי נתן זרע לאחיו לא רצה לתת זרע השדה לאחיו שלא רצה להשחית נחלתו. כמו שמצינו גבי רות ויאמר הגואל לא אוכל לגאול פן אשחית נחלתי.

In the HaMaor Mikraos Gedolos, it adds in a few words, that "zera" here literally (*al derech hapshat*) means "the crops he would plant."

So altogether the (very-much-rated-G) sentence reads:

> וַיֵּ֣דַע אוֹנָ֔ן כִּ֛י לֹּ֥א ל֖וֹ יִהְיֶ֣ה הַזָּ֑רַע וְהָיָ֞ה
> אִם־בָּ֨א אֶל־אֵ֤שֶׁת אָחִיו֙ וְשִׁחֵ֣ת אַ֔רְצָה לְבִלְתִּ֥י
> נְתׇן־זֶ֖רַע לְאָחִֽיו׃
>
> Onan **figured** that he wouldn't have **the crops**, and that should
> he impregnate his brother's wife, that would **ruin** [or **leave unused**] the **land**, and he didn't want to give **crops** to his brother.

What, exactly, was he worried about? How would getting her pregnant affect the crops/fields? Just that he would be too busy raising children? And who does he not want to have crops -- his deceased older brother, his younger brother, or some other relative?

Or does the last phrase read: *not to sacrifice his crops for the sake of his brother*? (I.e. he should have children for the sake of his brother, but he was too committed to his farming?)

(I saw R' Munk's translation on Sefaria, and I'm still not seeing the logic here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chizkuni cites [Ruth 4:6](https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2904.htm#6), regarding Ploni's refusal to marry Ruth, for comparison:

> וַיֹּאמֶר הַגֹּאֵל לֹא אוּכַל לִגְאָל לִי פֶּן אַשְׁחִית אֶת נַחֲלָתִי

Translation (Mechon-Mamre):

> And the near kinsman said: 'I cannot redeem it for myself, lest I mar mine own inheritance...'

See [Ralbag (Ruth 4:6)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ralbag_Ruth.4.6):

> לא אוכל לגאל לי פן אשחית את נחלתי רוצה לומר שאם אפרע כסף הקנין הנה האמת אשחית את נחלתי שלא יהיה לי ממה לשכור עובדי אדמתי ותשאר שממה או אולי אצטרך למכור מנחלתי וכבר נתבאר בתורה שאין ראוי לגאל כשהיה הדבר בזה האופן

Translation:

> 'I cannot redeem it for myself, lest I mar mine own inheritance': That is to say, 'If I pay the acquisition money, I will indeed destroy my inheritance. For I will not have the wherewithal to hire workers for my land, and [the land] will remain desolate, or maybe I will have to sell off [parts] of my inheritance.'

The Chizkuni, following the Ralbag's interpretation there, draws a parallel between Ploni, Ruth's redeemer manqué, and Onan, whom Chizkuni portrays as Tamar's redeemer manqué. Chizkuni would paraphrase *B'reishis* 38:9 as something like:

> וַיֵּדַע אוֹנָן כִּי לֹּא לוֹ יִהְיֶה הַזָּרַע -- Onan thought<sup>1</sup> that he would lose his own crops.

> וְהָיָה אִם בָּא אֶל אֵשֶׁת אָחִיו וְשִׁחֵת אַרְצָה -- And [Onan thought that] if he would marry his brother's wife he would destroy his own land  [because he would have to redirect his limited financial resources towards his marriage with Tamar and would not be able to afford to hire workers to plow and sow his own land].<sup>2</sup>

> לְבִלְתִּי נְתָן זֶרַע לְאָחִיו -- [Thus,] he refused to [marry Tamar and refused to thereby] divert his [financial resources for] his own planting towards his [obligation to his departed] brother.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Chizkuni (ad loc.): "וידע אונן: כסבור היה כמו הֲיָדוֹעַ נֵדַע"</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Chizkuni: "אמר בלבו אם אבא אל אשת אחי אשחית את ארצי שלא אמצא מי חורשה ומי זורעה"</sub>

<sup>3</sup><sub>Chizkuni: "לא רצה לתת זרע השדה לאחיו שלא רצה להשחית נחלתו כמו שמצינו גבי רות ויאמר הגואל לא אוכל לגאול פן אשחית נחלתי"</sub>

Comment: "towards his brother" meaning the memory of his departed brother? Or his younger, living one? And is his concern that marrying Tamar is the expense, or having children? (Or perhaps he mentally bundled that as one big expense.)

Comment: @Shalom Onan refused to allocate his resources towards his obligation to his departed brother. Judging by the Ralbag on *Rus*, I'd venture to say that the marriage itself would constitute the expense.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the concern was the children, which seems funny as in most agrarian societies, you want to have kids around to help. So it seems Chizkuni would read that Er was too selfish to be a father for whatever reasons (see Chizkuni on the earlier verse), and Onan too selfish to be a husband!